# Copying a file from my Azure web role to another computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, azure

I have an Azure web role and a separate computer. Both of them are on the same network and both share certain folders which the other can access. If I go on my Azure web role, through remote desktop, I can go to the other computer's shared folder using `\\comp1\folder` and *add/remove/edit* files there.

I have a few image files on my web role which I need to copy to the separate computer.
These images are uploaded to the web role and stored there.

**How can I copy those images that are on the web role, to my other computer?**

I have tried using `File.Copy` but it always gives me *Access Denied* errors.

I tried doing:

```
File.Copy(Server.MapPath("~/image/a.jpg"),@"\\comp1\folder\b.jpg");
```

Result: `UnauthorizedAccessException`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access the file system on Azure like that, except through Local Storage?

To quote [Bill Wilder](http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/06/12/azure-faq-can-i-write-to-the-file-system-on-windows-azure/)

> Any of your code running in either (a) ASP.NET (e.g., default.aspx or
>   default.aspx.cs) or (b) WebRole.cs/WorkerRole.cs (e.g., methods
>   OnStartup, OnRun, and OnStop which are derived from RoleEntryPoint
>   class) will not have permission to write to the file system.

You can [read and write to the Local Storage system](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Windows-Azure-Local-File-Storage-How-To-Guide-and-Warnings.aspx)

```
    try 
    {
        LocalResource myConfigsStorage = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("myConfigs"); 
        string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(myConfigStorage.RootPath + "myFile.txt"); 
        //... do your work with s 
    } 
    catch (Exception myException) 
    { 
        ...    }
```

But having always used Azure with more than one instance I have never seen the need for local storage and used the blob store instead.

Read more: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Windows-Azure-Local-File-Storage-How-To-Guide-and-Warnings.aspx#ixzz26ce8rXpk

Comment: What if I would use Azure blobs? I can successfully write my file to a blob(and can confirm it is there) but how would I read it on the other machine?

Comment: That's a whole other question really. One option is Machine1 writes to blob storage and updates a database with a record of the write. Machine2 looks at the database, sees the record of the write and requests the blob.

Comment: My question is how to read from a blob on the 'Machine2' since it doesn't have the azure project on it.

Comment: using the Blob Service REST API or via .net code. Machine2 does not need the Azure project on it to be able to access the Azure blob store.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide me a link to where I can read on how to achieve this? I need to read it using c#. Thanks !

Comment: In the link that you provided it says that I can read a blob using http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob but where exactly do I need to place the link? I can't access my blob account by just using typing it in the browser.

Comment: I've seen nothing close to c# code from those articles, I don't know what the rest means or does.

Comment: I've answered your original question. Start a new one if you need to.

Comment: Great. Can you tick this as the answer then please.